# PHP Laravel DropDown List

Tags: php, laravel

I am new to web development, and i want to know whether or not it is possible to have a dropdown button, populated with different types of posts such as recipes, blog and pictures.

I have searched around and could not find anything yet.

So far I have done this

```
@can('update', $user->profile)
    <span>Type Of Post: </span>
    <select style="width: 200px" class="typeofpost" id="type_post_id">
        <option value="0" disabled="true" selected="true">-Select-</option>
        <option href="/p/create">Add New Image</option>
        <option>Add New Recipe</option>
        <option>Add New Meal Plan</option>
        <option>Add New Blog</option>
    </select>
@endcan
```

However although it is showing the list as a drop down w/ the Add new image i expected it to follow through to the link. is there a better option?

Comment: Yes it's possible. If you want an extensive answer, you should probably be specific

Comment: @ClementSam Sorry, I edited my question. Also i want it so my user has multiple posting options. So when they select whichever option from the drop down it would then direct them to a create page which specifically posts to the chosen style. I think my code above explains it a little

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're on the right track.

There are two approaches here. One is to handle the redirection using javascript.

That would look like this:

```html
@can('update', $user->profile)
<span>Type Of Post: </span>
<select style="width: 200px" class="typeofpost" id="type_post_id">
  <option disabled selected>-Select-</option>
  <option value="/image/create">Add New Image</option>
  <option value="/recipe/create">Add New Recipe</option>
  <option value="/mealplan/create">Add New Meal Plan</option>
  <option value="/blog/create">Add New Blog</option>
</select>
@endcan
```

```js
document.getElementById('type_post_id')
  .addEventListener('change', function(event) {
    location.href = event.target.value
  })
```

The other method that I prefer is to create your own dropdown using your own markup and styles. There are a number of good examples returned by a quick google search for CSS button dropdown

Comment: Thank you!, will try it out now... I'll let you know how it goes.

Comment: Thanks again, using the CSS button dropdown was the best bet. Gave a cleaner response and button.